# Write in a TextBox inside a function

Tags: c#

Im working with Kinect and measuring speed of joints. I have an method to measure the speed, and i want to write it in a text box in the GUI of the kinect application.

How can i do that inside my function? How can i pass the TextBox as an parametrer to the function?

```
public void Velocity(double[] doub)
{
    double speed;
    // MY CODE for speed aquisiction
    speed = deltax/deltat //the deltas are calculated above, no need to show it here
    Boxname.Text = speed.ToString(); //i want this to work inside the method
}
```

Comment: To make it clearer, references to the TextBox name inside the Velocity method causes errors in compilations, so i have to write in it outisde of the function.

Comment: Instead of mutating the textbox, have the function return the calculated value and let the caller change the texbox value. Side effects like this are bad.

Comment: Best answer to this would probably depend on what you're using for your GUI.

Comment: @McAden No, I'd say asawyer's answer is the best answer, because then the function doesn't need to *care* about what he's using for his GUI.

Comment: @Servy - My comment was on the OP, not related to the other comments. I agree that the TextBox should not be updated within this function. How the TextBox **should** get updated is a different matter that needs more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing `Textbox` is not a very good option. As you are creating a function so it would be more meaningful that function does its work and return calculated value. So wherever I required to get the value, I can get by simply calling a function.

In this way I can use the value in whatever purpose I would like e.g. setting the text of textbox.

It would be great if you do something like this

```
public double Velocity(double[] doub)
{
    double speed;
    // MY CODE for speed aquisiction
    speed = deltax/deltat //the deltas are calculated above, no need to show it here
    return speed;
}

// update the text of textbox by calling the function wherever required.
Boxname.Text = Velocity().ToString();
```

Comment: I agree with Servy, also the function is poorly named, something like `GetVelocity` or `CalculateVelocity` would be more appropriate. (This isn't a criticism to the answer, just a note to @Diedre)